# How can I resolve the increase in index size when using nested objects in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

The total number of data is 1 billion.

When I configure an index by setting some fields of data as nested objects, the number of data increases and the index size increases.

There are about 20 nested objects in a document.

When I index 1 billion documents, the number of indexes is 20 billion, and the index size is about 20TB.

However, when I remove nested objects, the number of indexes is 1 billion, and the index size is about 5TB.

It's simply removed nested object and can not provide services with this index structure.

I know why nested objects have a higher index count than a simple object configuration.
But I ask why the index is four times larger and how to fix it.

version of elasticsearch : 5.1.1

The Sample Data is as follows:

nested object Mapping : idds, ishs, resources, versions

```
    {
"fileType": {
    "asdFormat": 1
},
"dac": {
    "pe": {
    "cal": {
        "d1": -4634692645508395000,
        "d2": -5805223225419042000,
        "d3": -1705264433
    },
    "bytes": "6a7068e0",
    "entry": 0,
    "count": 7,
    "css": {
        "idh": 0,
        "ish": 0,
        "ifh": 0,
        "ioh": 0,
        "ish": 0,
        "ied": 0,
        "exp": 0,
        "imp": 0,
        "sec": 0
    },
    "ff": {
        "field1": 23117,
        "field2": 144,
        "field3": 3,
        "field4": 0,
        "field5": 4,
        "field6": 0,
        "field7": 65535,
        "field8": 0,
        "field9": 184,
        "field10": 0,
        "field11": 0,
        "field12": 0,
        "field13": 64,
        "field14": 0,
        "field15": 40104,
        "field16": 64563,
        "field17": 0,
        "field18": 0,
        "field19": 0,
        "field20": 0,
        "field21": 0,
        "field22": 0,
        "field23": 0,
        "field24": 0,
        "field25": 0,
        "field26": 0,
        "field27": 0,
        "field28": 0,
        "field29": 0,
        "field30": 0,
        "field31": 224
    },
    "ifh": {
        "mc": 332,
        "nos": 3,
        "time": 1091599505,
        "ps": 0,
        "ns": 0,
        "soh": 224,
        "chart": 271
    },
    "ioh": {
        "magic": 267,
        "mlv": 7,
        "nlv": 10,
        "soc": 80384,
        "soid": 137216,
        "soud": 0,
        "aep": 70290,
        "boc": 4096,
        "bod": 86016,
        "aib": "16777216",
        "si": 4096,
        "fa": 512,
        "mosv": 5,
        "nosv": 1,
        "miv": 5,
        "niv": 1,
        "msv": 4,
        "nsv": 0,
        "wv": 0,
        "si": 262144,
        "sh": 1024,
        "cs": 0,
        "ss": 2,
        "dllchart": 32768,
        "ssr": "262144",
        "ssc": "262144",
        "ssh": "1048576",
        "shc": "4096",
        "lf": 0,
        "nor": 16
    },
    "idds": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "address": 77504,
        "size": 300
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "address": 106496,
        "size": 134960
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "address": 5264,
        "size": 28
        },
        {
        "id": 11,
        "address": 592,
        "size": 300
        },
        {
        "id": 12,
        "address": 4096,
        "size": 1156
        }
    ],
    "ishs": [
        {
        "id": 0,
        "name": ".text",
        "size": 79920,
        "address": 4096,
        "srd": 80384,
        "ptr": 1024,
        "ptrl": 0,
        "ptl": 0,
        "nor": 0,
        "nol": 0,
        "chart": 3758096480,
        "ex1": 60404022,
        "ex2": 61903965,
        "ex": 61153993.5
        },
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": ".data",
        "size": 17884,
        "address": 86016,
        "srd": 2048,
        "ptr": 81408,
        "ptrl": 0,
        "ptl": 0,
        "nor": 0,
        "nol": 0,
        "chart": 3221225536,
        "ex1": 27817394,
        "ex2": -1,
        "ex": 27817394
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "name": ".rsrc",
        "size": 155648,
        "address": 106496,
        "srd": 135680,
        "ptr": 83456,
        "ptrl": 0,
        "ptl": 0,
        "nor": 0,
        "nol": 0,
        "chart": 3758096448,
        "ex1": 38215005,
        "ex2": 46960547,
        "ex": 42587776
        }
    ],
    "resources": [
        {
        "id": 2,
        "count": 3,
        "hash": 658696779440676200
        },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "count": 14,
        "hash": 4671329014159995000
        },
        {
        "id": 5,
        "count": 30,
        "hash": -6413921454731808000
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "count": 17,
        "hash": 8148183923057157000
        },
        {
        "id": 14,
        "count": 4,
        "hash": 8004262029246967000
        },
        {
        "id": 16,
        "count": 1,
        "hash": 7310592488525726000
        },
        {
        "id": 2147487240,
        "count": 2,
        "hash": -7466967570237519000
        }
    ],
    "upx": {
        "path": "xps",
        "d64": 3570326159822345700
    },
    "versions": [
        {
        "language": 1042,
        "codePage": 1200,
        "companyName": "Microsoft Corporation",
        "fileDescription": "Files and Settings Transfer Wizard",
        "fileVersion": "5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)",
        "internalName": "Microsoft",
        "legalCopyright": "Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1999-2000",
        "originalFileName": "calc.exe",
        "productName": "Microsoft(R) Windows (R) 2000 Operating System",
        "productVersion": "5.1.2600.2180"
        }
    ],
    "import": {
        "dll": [
        "GDI32.dll",
        "KERNEL32.dll",
        "USER32.dll",
        "ole32.dll",
        "ADVAPI32.dll",
        "COMCTL32.dll",
        "SHELL32.dll",
        "msvcrt.dll",
        "comdlg32.dll",
        "SHLWAPI.dll",
        "SETUPAPI.dll",
        "Cabinet.dll",
        "LOG.dll",
        "MIGISM.dll"
        ],
        "count": 14,
        "d1": -149422985349905340,
        "d2": -5344971616648705000,
        "d3": 947564411044974800
    },
    "ddSec0": {
        "d1": -3007779250746558000,
        "d4": -2515772085422514700
    },
    "ddSec2": {
        "d2": -4422408392580008000,
        "d4": -8199520081862749000
    },
    "ddSec3": {
        "d1": -8199520081862749000
    },
    "cdp": {
        "d1": 787971,
        "d2": 39,
        "d3": 101980696,
        "d4": 3,
        "d5": 285349133
    },
    "cde": {
        "d1": 67242500,
        "d2": 33687042,
        "d3": 218303490,
        "d4": 1663632132,
        "d5": 0
    },
    "cdm": {
        "d1": 319293444,
        "d2": 2819,
        "d3": 168364553,
        "d4": 50467081,
        "d5": 198664
    },
    "cdb": {
        "d1": 0,
        "d2": 0,
        "d3": 0,
        "d4": 0,
        "d5": 0
    },
    "mm": {
        "d0": -3545367393134139000,
        "d1": 1008464166428372900,
        "d2": -6313842304565328000,
        "d3": -5015640502060250000
    },
    "ser": 17744,
    "ideal": 0,
    "map": 130,
    "ol": 0
    }
},
"fileSize": 219136
```

}

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings. "Indexing 1 document with 100 nested fields actually indexes 101 documents as each nested document is indexed as a separate hidden document." You can try setting index.mapping.nested_fields.limit.